# Bitcoin Wallet for Android - permission denied decrypting the wallet backup file using OpenSSL

Tags: wallet-recovery, bitcoin-wallet-app, android

I've followed the advice found on the https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/blob/master/wallet/README.recover.md, but I'm having issues decrypted a wallet backup file

When I run below line

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in bitcoin-wallet-backup-2017-12-25 > bitcoin-wallet-decrypted-backup
```

I got below error message

```
$ openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in bitcoin-wallet-backup-2017-12-25 > bitcoin-wallet-decrypted-backup 
bitcoin-wallet-backup-2017-12-25: Permission denied 
140623991867032:error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:bss_file.c:398:fopen('bitcoin-wallet-backup-2017-12-25','r') 
140623991867032:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
```

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have the permissions to read the file `bitcoin-wallet-backup-2017-12-25`. Check your permissions on the file and make sure that your user is allowed to read the file.